# readelf utility for Visual Studio C++ ABI and VS compiled objects?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, objdump, abi, readelf

I'm looking for alternatives to the `readelf` and `objdump` duo when using Visual Studio for compiling C++ source code and investigating `lib`, `obj` and `dll`.

I'm aware that MinGW offers a porting of this tools but I'm looking for something with an official support for the Microsoft C++ ABI.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 if this matter.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`dumpbin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c.aspx) utility is included with Visual Studio.  It has [many options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/756as972.aspx).

Comment: missing vcamp110.dll, found 3 copies of this dll under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\redist\x64`, what i need to do now ? I have already runned vcvarsall.bat with both user privileges and administrative privileges but it doesn't work.

Comment: nevermind, i run vcvarsall.bat again and it works now, but only for this session.

Comment: if I'm only interested in determining the architecture and the "bitness" this is the best way to do it ?  `dumpbin /headers my.lib | findstr /i "machine magic"`